# How do I hide a label in CSS when a label ID does not appear to exist?

Tags: html, css

I am very new to CSS/HTML, and I'm struggling to find the logic behind this code.

Here is the HTML Code from the website:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-3 dashboard_chapter_label">
    <label>Extra Guests</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="extra_price_per_guest">
      Extra Price per guest per day in $
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="extra_price_per_guest" class="form-control" size="40" name="extra_price_per_guest" value="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to hide the label `Extra Guests` but there does not appear to be an ID for this label (i.e. `Extra_Guests`) for me to apply a `display: hidden` command against. Other labels in this web theme have specific fields (i.e. `extra_price_per_guest` and it has been simple to hide them with a `display: hidden` command but I've found this and a few other fields don't have a specific ID. Or at least they don't appear to.

I have been able to successfully hide all labels in Column 3 (where `Extra Guests` resides) at once by using the following line of code:

```css
.col-md-3.dashboard_chapter_label label {
  display: none;
}
```

But... that hides all labels in Column 3 (every label above and below `Extra Guests` on the webpage) and I want to isolate this specific label. I just don't know how to do that when `Extra Guests` does not appear to have an ID like `Extra_Guests`.

I have tried the following lines of code to hide `Extra Guests` from the web-page:

```css
.col-md-12.div.col-md-3.dashboard_chapter_label label[for="Extra Guests"]  {
  display: none;
}
```

As well as:

```css
.col-md-12.div.col-md-3.dashboard_chapter_label label[for="Extra_Guests"]  {
  display: none;
}
```

As well as:

```css
.col-md-3.dashboard_chapter_label label {
  display: none;
}
```

The code above hid the label, but it also hid all labels in Column 3 on this web page, not the specific label I wanted to hide.

I am hoping that there is a way to successfully identify the `Extra Guests` text and hide it. I would like to replace it with different text.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I gave this a shot using the code as follows:

.dashboard_chapter_label label .col-md-3.dashboard_chapter_label > label {   display: none; }

That did not appear to do anything, but it did not effect anything. Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 1):

I hope It will help you.

```css
label:not([for]) {
    display: none;
}
```

or to be more specific

```css
.dashboard_chapter_label > label:not([for]) {
    display: none;
}
```

or

```css
.col-md-3.dashboard_chapter_label > label:not([for]) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I think this got me closer, but still running into one issue. When I used the code from your last example, it successfully hid the "Extra Guests" label, but it also hid every label beneath Extra Guests. Thankfully, it did not hide the labels above/prior to "Extra Guests" on the web page. Is there a way to further isolate so I don't hide labels after/beneath "Extra Guests"?

This is the code I used from your example:
.col-md-3.dashboard_chapter_label > label:not([for]) {
    display: none;
}

Comment: Try something like `label:not([for]}:first-of-type` or `label:not([for]}:first-child`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).